# What are the best jQuery practices to use the same effect on different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a chat support fixed on the left of my browser, I want to show and hide it using jQuery, I already did it by using the show() and hide() function but, when I want to apply the same jQuery effect on subsequent layers it does nothing, it just applies to the first element, what I want to ask is:

What is the best way to do this, I'm learning jQuery and have done some little things with this library but I can't figure how to do this without just copy and paste the same effect, should I use a "for" method?.

I leave my code below with a JS Fiddle example so you guys can figure out what's going on:

HTML Markup:

```
    <div id="support_left">
        <div id="support_show">
            <figure id="show_control">
                <img src="../img/chat.png" alt="Chat" />
            </figure>

            <div id="show_item">
                <p class="support_cyan">Chat with sales <span class="close">X</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div id="support_show">
            <figure id="show_control">
                <img src="../img/call.png" alt="Call" />
            </figure>

            <div id="show_item">
                <p class="support_orange">Chat with sales <span class="close">X</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div id="support_show">
            <figure id="show_control">
                <img src="../img/mail.png" alt="Email" />
            </figure>

            <div id="show_item">
                <p class="support_green">Chat with sales <span class="close">X</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#show_item').hide();
$('#show_control').click(function(){
    $('#show_item').show();
 });

$('.close').click(function(){ 
    $('#show_item').hide();
 });
```

Link to the JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/45hsd6dp/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs need to be unique. If you want to target multiple elements, use classes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/45hsd6dp/4/

Comment: Hehe it works, thank so much, but now it shows me all elements, what is the best way to just show the clicked element?

Comment: You need to use context, i.e. `$(this)`.

Comment: @Alex One question at a time makes them most useful to other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, change all your IDs to classes. **IDs must be unique** and how jQuery handles multiple instances of IDs is up to how individual browser/vendor decides to do with it. The behaviour is technically undefined and the browser will only select the first occurence, usually.

You will need to give your show and hide functions a context when the click event is fired. With your current script, you are telling jQuery that:

> Whenever a click event is registered for any elements with the class `.show_control`, show **ALL** items that has the class `.show_item`.

See that there is no context in your function that is bound to the click event.

To give your event listening a context, always use `$(this)`, which restricts the function to elements of interest:

```
$('.show_item').hide();
$('.show_control').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.show_item').show();
});

$('.close').click(function(){ 
    $(this).parent('.show_item').hide();
});
```

In layman's words, the function tells jQuery:

> When `.show_control` is clicked it, search for it's immediate, next sibling that has the class of `.show_item`, and show it.

See that the statement has context, because `$(this)` restricts jQuery to the context of the element being clicked on. **Depending on your markup, you will have to rely on various jQuery methods to transverse the DOM**, such as `.next()`, `.prev()`, `.parent()`, `.parents()`, `.find()`, `.children()`, `.siblings()` and etc. All these functions are well-documented on the jQuery API, make sure you check that out.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/45hsd6dp/6/

Comment: This is actually what I wanted to do, I just want to point that there is no need to use $('.this).parent, since we just want to hide the element when we click, thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Using `$(this).parent()` to hide the element for closing is still, IMHO, safer than a blanket, contextless selector hide. While it may not be relevant to your example, it is still good practice. Imagine if you want to use `.toggle()` or `.toggleClass()`, where context is still important.